# How to make buttom send event to another control

Tags: ios, objective-c, events, send

I need call Touch Up Inside event in TextField when i push the bottom, how can i do this? As result when i push the bottom, the other control (textfield) becomes active and keyboard appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When button is pressed you can call:

```
[myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```